# PHP 7.3 - Laravel 7 - Is there a way to fake run a function, make sure it doesn't give errors and only then actually run it?

Tags: php, laravel

**PHP 7.3 - Laravel 7**
I try to explain myself. I'll say that I'm a junior developer.

I have created a management platform that does not *usually* generate errors. It is mainly used by people who are not very experienced. And those rare times that there is an error *"they get scared"*; they would rather see a blank page.

So my question is ,

is there a way to make PHP *"virtually"* execute a function and *only if there are no errors* does it really execute it otherwise go back to the previous page?
(I hope there are no errors in the text; I used a translator)
Thank you very much

**EDIT**
I'll add one more thing. The function also contains saves in databases for example. And maybe PHP encounters an error **after** this save. Does the try/catch method prevent saving to database or "go back" only when it encounters the error? Thanks

Comment: Broadly speaking PHP can't "catch" all possible errors so (again broadly speaking) this is not possible. It might be possible to catch *most* errors if you wrap the function call in a `try { function() } catch (\Throwable $e) { /* redirect */ }`

Comment: Some exceptions describe HTTP error codes from the server. For example, this may be a "page not found" error (404), an "unauthorized error" (401) or even a developer generated 500 error.

Comment: Thank you @apokryfos

Comment: Thanks @STA for the clarification; actually I already handle those errors differently (with redirects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Added DB Transactions to solve the note about this issue.

You can wrap any function in a try-catch statement which would allow you to accomplish the same result albeit through different means. An example for use in a controller would be:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {

    // your custom function here, which may fail
    // Also add in any Database transactions, eloquent models or DB statements

    DB::commit(); // otherwise it doesn't save anything in the database
    return view();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    // This will only run if the above throws an exception
    DB::rollback();
    return back()->withErrors(['message'=>'']);
}
```

Here's a great resource by a well known Laravel Dev [Database Transactions in Laravel by Caleb Porzio](https://fideloper.com/laravel-database-transactions)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Azeame . Could you please take a look at the question I've added?

Comment: @marco987 updated my response to address the database issue

Comment: Thank you @Azeame ! It's a **fantastic** solution that I ignored! I respect you ;-)

Comment: @marco987 no problem buddy! Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hi @Azeame, I added DB::commit() otherwise it doesn't save anything in DB!!! I just noticed this problem

Comment: LOL, yeah I didn't even notice I forgot that.